# Errors in examples of Vardi's paper "Linear Temporal Logic and Linear Dynamic Logic on Finite Traces"

Tags: regular-expressions, check-my-answer, linear-temporal-logic

The paper [Linear Temporal Logic and Linear Dynamic Logic on Finite Traces](https://www.cs.rice.edu/%7Evardi/papers/ijcai13.pdf) has the following examples on page 4:

**Q1**. (**Update to Q1**: solved. See the comment by DCTLib.) The first example says that the REf (reg-expr over fin words) $\varphi^* \equiv$ ☐$\phi$

[image: example 1]

I disagree: the LTLf formula ☐$\phi$ says that in *every* moment of the trace the formula $\phi$ holds while the REf $\varphi^*$ says there exists $n$ such that $\varphi;\varphi;...\varphi$ n times matches the whole word. Example: take the word $abab$ and $\varphi = (a;b)$, then $abab \models (a;b)^*$ whereas $abab \not\models $ ☐$(a;b)$. Agreed?

**Q2**. Another example:

[image: example 3]

Let me first note that the very first part $true^*$ already corresponds to ◇(...) and not to ☐, hence it cannot have the form ☐(...). Now, I assume the operator priorities are such that we have $true^*;(\neg \psi + (true^*; \varphi))$. This corresponds to ◇(Last ∧ ( → )). So it is not what they claim. Agreed?

Many thanks.

Comment: The first example seems to contain a typo by mixing "\varphi" and "\phi". Phi was a bit earlier defined to be a propositional formula, and then this example appears to be fine.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, you can ask them separately.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).